# How to grab video sequence using basler ip camera in opencv 2.1?

Tags: camera, ip

I could not stream over the ip camera because it say it return null.
It stated warning:

```
Error opening file c:\user\vp\ocv\opencv\src\highgui\cvcap_ffmpeg.cpp:452
```

hope someone can help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve image data from OpenCV directly from IP cameras. You need to acces raw data through the Pylon API (`get char* data`), and then copy to `iplimage`->`imageData`.

Then you could grab every frame with OpenCV, but don't use `ffmpeg`, try VideoForWindows (`vfw`), it's easier to use and give less problems with OpenCV.

The error you're getting is due to some problems ffmpeg trying to find the codec you selected, or an incorrect configuration.

Comment: Thank you for reponding. For your information, the device (http://www.sourcesecurity.com/technical-details/cctv/image-capture/ip-cameras/basler-bip-640c-dn.html) I'm using can't use with Pylon Api like the Ace model.